# Invoke-Sqlcmd not working in SQL

Tags: sql, invoke-sqlcmd

Im using the following command in SQL Powershell to generate csv of data returned by SQL.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "myp" -ServerInstance "." | Export-Csv -Path "d:\data\MyDatabaseSizes.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above command works perfectly fine in SQL Power Shell. but when I tried to run in from SQL using the following code

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "myp" -ServerInstance "." | Export-Csv -Path "d:\data\MyDatabaseSizes.csv" -NoTypeInformation'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

it give error that

'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Anyone please help me in running the command from SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Not working.. same error

Comment: Sorry my bad, after adding powershell.exe in the beginning now there is another error     'Export-Csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0):

`xp_cmdmshell` executes Windows shell commands, not PowerShell commands.  You can of course call PowerShell from within the Windows shell, for example like this:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ''myp'' -ServerInstance ''.'' ^| Export-Csv -Path ''d:\data\MyDatabaseSizes.csv'' -NoTypeInformation'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe -c "' + @cmd + '"'
```

Note that:

- I have replaced the double quotes in the PowerShell command with single quotes (escaped for SQL) so I can use double quotes in the Windows command.  If you need double quotes in the PowerShell, you're better off having the PowerShell script in a file to avoid all this
- You may also need more parameters (e.g. to set the execution policy).  [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help) has more help on PowerShell command line switches
- Pipe characters in command line arguments need to be escaped with `^`

Comment: Hello, When I execute the above Code in SQL it gives error 'Export-Csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: you need to escape pipes in the command line (if not actually being used as a shell pipe) with a caret.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob. But when I execute your query I removed | character. And in the 3rd line it gave me error in concatinating. Please help can you please create a working query for me thanks