# Invoke SQL command not working in Power shell core 6.0.2

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-core

invoke sql command is not working it throws a below error can some one help me with it

> invoke-sqlcmd : The term 'invoke-sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At
>   D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Code\HCP_HCO_External_ID_Network_Updates.ps1:7
>   char:9
>   + $result=invoke-sqlcmd -inputFile "D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\cfg\SQL Scr ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (invoke-sqlcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> invoke-sqlcmd : The term 'invoke-sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At
>   D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Code\HCP_HCO_External_ID_Network_Updates.ps1:8
>   char:10
>   + $result1=invoke-sqlcmd -inputFile "D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\cfg\SQL Sc ...
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (invoke-sqlcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because
>   it is null. At
>   D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Code\HCP_HCO_External_ID_Network_Updates.ps1:9
>   char:10
>   + $result |export-csv "D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Out\HCP_EXTID_Update_Adh ...
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
>
> Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because
>   it is null. At
>   D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Code\HCP_HCO_External_ID_Network_Updates.ps1:10
>   char:11
>   + $result1 |export-csv "D:\Process\VeevaNetwork\Out\HCO_EXTID_Update_Ad ...
>   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206678/invoke-sqlcmd-doesnt-work-when-used-with-xp-cmdshell check link

Comment: check this also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193006/difficulties-working-with-powershell-invoke-sqlcmd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097340/invoke-sqlcmd-not-working-in-sql

Comment: Looks like you need [SqlServer Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017).